# Models of a Propositional Logic Program

Tags: logic

I'm new to answer sets and logic, and struggle to understand the definition of a model in the book I'm reading. Given the propositional logic Program

$a \leftarrow \\
c \leftarrow \sim b, \sim d \\
d \leftarrow a, \sim c$

where ~x is the default negation ("x is possibly false"). The book claims there are six models to this program with the following definition:

A set X $\subseteq$ A of ground atoms is a **model** of a propositional logic program P, if head(r) $\in$ X whenever body(r)+ $\subseteq$ X and body(r)- $\cap$ X = $\emptyset$ for every r $\in$ P. 
body(r)+ are the positive atoms of the body, body(r)- the default negated ones.

I have come up with two possible models: {a, c} and {a, d}, but they also claim {a, b, c, d} to be a model, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program may be rewritten in propositional logic as :

> $a$
>
> $(\lnot b \land \lnot d) \to c$
>
> $(a \land \lnot c) \to d$

and we have to find its *models*, i.e. the truth-assignements that simultaneously satisfy them.

As you correctly said, both $\{ a, c \}$ and $\{ a, d \}$ are models.

We will check the first one. With a truth-assignement $v$ such that :

> $v(a)=v(c)=$ **T**

we have $v(a \land \lnot c)=$ **F** and thus : $v((a \land \lnot c) \to d)$= **T** : a conditional with a *false* antecedent is *true*.

We have $v(c)=$ **T** and thus : $v((\lnot b \land \lnot d) \to c)$= **T** :  a conditional with a *true* consequent is *true*.

And obviously $v(a)=$ **T**.

Consider now : $\{ a, b, c, d \}$.

Again : $v(a)=$ **T** and with $v(c)=$ **T** we have : $v(a \land \lnot c)=$ **F** and so : $v((a \land \lnot c) \to d)$= **T**.

Finally : $v(d)=$ **T**, and thus : $v((a \land \lnot c) \to d)$= **T**.

---

We may "generalise" the above argument and conclude that :

> every set that includes one of the models $\{ a, c \}$ and $\{ a, d \}$ must also be a model.

This is why they are six :

> $\{ a, c \} , \{ a, d \} , \{ a, c, b \} , \{ a, c, d \} , \{ a, d, b \} , \{ a, b, c, d \}.$

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! Regarding my definition, does it basically mean if the rules apply the head CAN BE element of X? I'm struggling to apply the definition tbh

Comment: @oliver13 - what are head(r) and body(r) ? and what does it mean body(r)+ ⊆ ?

Comment: head(r) is the left side/consequent of a rule. body(r) is the right side/antecedent of the rule. The latter was missing X - fixed it now

Comment: @oliver13 - exactly. $a \to b$ is true either when $b$ is true or $a$ is false. Applied to $r$ like $b \leftarrow a$ it means that b=head(r) $\in X$ etc.