# Herbrand Base in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I've just studied the Least Herbrand Model, that is the intersection of every possible Herbrand Base.

So, i guess that it's possible to have an Herbrand Base with more elements than needed . Is it correct ?
If no, i dont understand the need to introduce the Least Herbrand model...

Comment: Can you add your definition of a Herbrand base? The definition I'm familiar with already entails minimality (for trivial reasons).

Comment: Nice :)
But, if your definition already entails minimality, what's the need for a least herbrand base ?

Comment: With the definition I know, there is no need for a least Herbrand base -- there is always a unique one. That's why I'm asking for the precise definition you're using. It might be the case that your definition doesn't imply minimality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Minimal models](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mjs/teaching/KnowledgeRep491/Fixpoint_Definite_491-2x1.pdf):

> The relation $⊆$ (subset) is a partial ordering for subsets of $\text {atoms}(P)$ of a *program* $P$, and therefore for Herbrand interpretations and Herbrand models. So we can talk of minimal Herbrand models.
>
> A Herbrand model is *minimal* if no proper subset of it is also a model.

Note that minimal does not imply unique, in general. A set of formulas might have several minimal Herbrand models.

For example, $\{ a ∨ b \}$ has the following Herbrand models: $\{ a, b \}, \{ a \}, \{ b \}$.

The models $\{ a \}$ and $\{ b \}$ are both minimal.

> The usual terminology for any partial ordering is that least means "the least" (i.e. unique minimal). So sometimes we speak of the *least Herbrand model*, which is the unique minimal model, if it exists.

Comment: Hi Mauro, 2 questions:

1) How is possible that the set $\left \{ a \right \}$ is a model ? It misses the b element
2) What the need of an herbrand model with more elements that the minimum needed ? As consequence, what possibilities offer an herbrand model that is not minimal ?

Comment: @Qwerto - this example is very simplified, using prop logic. If $a$ is TRUE, obviously it satisfy $a \lor b$.

Comment: So, $\left \{ a \right \}$ could have been a first order logic model ?

Comment: @Qwerto - YES; the Herbrand models of the "theory" $a \lor b$ are: $\{ a,b \}, \{ a \}, \{ b \}$..

Comment: what possibilities offer an herbrand model that is not minimal ?

Comment: @Qwerto - See the related post: [models-of-a-propositional-logic-program](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016707/models-of-a-propositional-logic-program).